# Flutter - How to achieve Row with same height as parent Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have to create a widget with the following design

[image]

I have a basic layout created for the same below. The below code is inside a Column.

```
                      Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: <Widget>[

                            /*******Outer Container********/
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5),
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text("1981-June-01"),
                                        SizedBox(width: 8),
                                        Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 8),

                                  /*******Inner Container********/
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                    child: Text("38Yrs"),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
```

The result i get is the following

[image]

There is still some unwanted padding between the parent container and the bounds of the Row that contains the two containers. I tried using IntrinsicHeight Widget but the UI stayed the same. I wrapped the outer container and the Row inside it with IntrinsicHeight Widget. One at a time and on both at the same time as well. But no change.

What i want to do is to remove that extra padding between the outer container and the inner container, and make the inner container border/height same as the Outer container. Am i missing something?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried wrapping with `IntrinsicHeight` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html

Comment: @Jack In the code i tried wrapping the Outer container, and the Row inside the outer container(on both at same time and one at a time as well) but nothing changed. The UI stayed the same. Tried hot reloading and hot restarting as well.

Comment: this is the simplified code: `Material(
elevation: 4,
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black45, width: 2)
),
clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
child: Row(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
children: <Widget>[
SizedBox(width: 8),
Text("1981-June-01"),
SizedBox(width: 4),
Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
SizedBox(width: 8),
Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 12),
child: Text("38Yrs"),
color: Colors.black26,
),
],
),
),`

Comment: add a self answer then...

Answer (score 1):

This is the output image:

[image: Output Image]

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      /*******Outer Container********/
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              //padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("  1981-June-01"),
                  SizedBox(width: 8),
                  Icon(Icons.calendar_today, size: 15),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 8),
             /*******Inner Container********/
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Text("38Yrs"),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(8),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(8)),
                // border: Border.fromBorderSide(BorderSide.none),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

As specified by @pskink in the comments under the question, a more simplified answer would be to replace the Row with the following code(copied from the comment under the question by @pskink)

```
Material(
                              elevation: 0,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                  side: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFDDDDDD), width: 1)),
                              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  SizedBox(width: 8),
                                  Text("1981-June-01", style: dateTextStyle),
                                  SizedBox(width: 8),
                                  Image.asset(
                                    "assets/images/widgetImages/calendar.png",
                                    width: 15,
                                    height: 15,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 8),
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 12),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "38Yrs",
                                      style: dateTextStyle,
                                    ),
                                    color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
```

This code is simpler in terms of number of widgets in the widget tree.